# how to use c# list the OOP way

Tags: c#, oop

im searching for an example but i dont know if im doing it right its hard for me to understand OOP. im creating an application. im trying to create a dashboard like for my modem(this is a usb modem) i use this to connect to the internet and send sms it is a huawei e353

this is my code but how can i convert it to OOP. im learning OOP. i brought a book but its hard to understand without a hands on so im creating this application for fun.

ModemReader.cs

```
class ModemReader
{
    public List<string> list = new List<string>();
    public void DetectModem(){

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_POTSModem");
        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get()){
            if ((string)queryObj["Status"] == "OK"){
               list.Add(queryObj["AttachedTo"] + " - " + System.Convert.ToString(queryObj["Description"]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in my form

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ModemReader detect = new ModemReader();
    detect.DetectModem();
    foreach (string value in detect.list)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(value);
    }
}
```

and after this im planning to use At commands to comunicate with the modem

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty opinion-based question and seems more like a code review.

The first important thing is that you need to use properties, use upper-case names for it and make it readonly since you don't want other people to modify your list outside of a class:

```
// C# 6.0 syntax, initialize in constructor for earlier versions
public List<string> Result { get; } = new List<string>();
```

Another notice is that you actually do not use your `List`, it is only used for saving the result of method execution. Why don't you make your method return it instead?

```
public static class ModemReader // or not static. it's up to you
{
    public static string[] DetectModems() // I would use string[] because you won't modify it
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_POTSModem");

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get()){
            if ((string)queryObj["Status"] == "OK"){
               result.Add(queryObj["AttachedTo"] + " - " + System.Convert.ToString(queryObj["Description"]));
            }
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And use it this way:

```
var modems = detect.DetectModems();
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(modems);
```

**Note:** As I already said, being OOP-way is not something like being `true` or `false`. Being OOP also doesn't mean to "be better" or "be correct". Any approach and any arthitecture can be better or worse in different situations. Furthermore, my corrections make your program "less OOP".
I just have given my observations and described an approach, which I would use, if I developed it, and it is far from a good one. You don't need to try to do everything in accordance with some rules - just make it easy to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Object oriented programming is the use of objects (you have a list of string objects) that is dynamic or programmatic, rather than static. What you have shown i would consider object oriented design, as you can dynamically detect and add new objects to your program based on variable input,

If you had it get input then do a massive list of checks then disregard the input after an action like adding it or ignoring it and moving on then that would NOT be object oriented programming.

OO is about data structures, like lists, arrays, or trees to store data and use it rather than perform 1 specific action and remove anything you dont need anymore

Sorry about not adding as a comment, but I dont have enough reputation yet to do so

Answer (score 0):

2 cents.

```
public interface IModem
{
    string GetName();
}

class HuaweiModem : IModem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

interface IModemReader
{
    List<IModem> DetectModems();
}

public class WmiModemReader : IModemReader
{
    public List<IModem> DetectModems()
    {
        List<IModem> result = new List<IModem>();
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_POTSModem");
        foreach (var queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            if ((string)queryObj["Status"] == "OK")
            {
                IModem modem = new HuaweiModem()
                {
                    Name = queryObj["AttachedTo"] + " - " + Convert.ToString(queryObj["Description"])
                };
                result.Add(modem);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then in your program use like this:

```
IModemReader modemReader = new WmiModemReader();
var modems = modemReader.DetectModems();
foreach (var modem in modems)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(modem.GetName());
}
```

In this approach you can see some concepts of OOP like inheritance, polymorphism.